# Use of undeclared identifier: ASIdentifierManager

Tags: ios, ios6, admob, undeclared-identifier

I am using the following code to show the unique identifier to be used for admob test apps.

This is with my applicationDidFinishLaunching...

```
// Print IDFA (from AdSupport Framework) for iOS 6 and UDID for iOS < 6.
if (NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager")) {
    NSLog(@"GoogleAdMobAdsSDK ID for testing: %@" ,
          [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"GoogleAdMobAdsSDK ID for testing: %@" ,
          [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]);
}
```

I get an error when building 'Use of undeclared identifier: ASIdentifierManager'

I have the AdSupport framework linked and can access the files the identifier manager is declared in, but it still doesn't recognise that?

I have cleaned build folder, restarted xCode same result.

Comment: Which line specifically are you getting the error in?

Comment: [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString]);

Comment: Have you imported headers from the framework?

Comment: #import <AdSupport/ASIdentifierManager.h>

Comment: No I hadn't as I assumed by them being in the 'Link Binary With Libraries' I didn't need to? Please submit as an answer it resolves the issue

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Have you imported headers from the framework?

```
#import <AdSupport/ASIdentifierManager.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer! if it is a framework add the beginning path. The example that repaired my error was:

```
#import "CoreMotion/CMMotionActivityManager.h"
```

I was incorrect as I only added the .h file.

```
#import "CMMotionActivityManger.h"  ---  This was incorrect and generated an error.
```